# How to prevent QWebEngineView to grab focus on setHtml(...) and load(...) calls?

Tags: qt, focus, qtwebengine

I have created simple Qt Window Layout with `QTreeView` and `QWebEngineView`: after selecting some item in the tree view, the Web engine view shows some content. The problem is what when `QWebEngineView::setHtml(...)` or `load(...)` is called the tree view loses keyboard focus and Web engine view gets it. This causes difficulties when selecting items with keyboard in the tree view. So, how to prevent the tree view focus lost?

I tried to use `QTextBrowser` instead of `QWebEngineView`. It doesn't have this problem, but it is not suitable for complex HTML pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose we have:

```
QWebEngineView *webView = new QWebEngineView;
```

#### For Qt 5.8 and newer

The problem can be solved by tweaking settings:

```
webView->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::FocusOnNavigationEnabled, false);
```

The sample code: https://github.com/rmisev/FocusWidget/tree/if-qt-5.8

*References:*

- [QWebEngineView::settings()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html#settings)
- [QWebEngineSettings Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#details)
- [QWebEngineSettings::setAttribute(](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#setAttribute)[WebAttribute attribute](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#WebAttribute-enum)[, bool on)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#setAttribute)
- [QTBUG-52999](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52999)

#### For Qt 5.7 and earlier

The simplest solution (also pointed by @Netrix) is to call:

```
webView->setEnabled(false);
```

But this disables keyboard input to the `webView`.

To solve this problem I created the simple `FocusWidget` class as parent widget for `webView`, which works as follows:

1. Initially it disables `webView` (`webView->setEnabled(false)`), so prevents to take focus on `load(...)`, `setHtml(...)` calls.
2. When `FocusWidget` gets focus, it enables and forwards focus to `webView`, so enables keyboard input.
3. When `webView` and its children loses focus, `FocusWidget` disables `webView` again

The source code and sample application: https://github.com/rmisev/FocusWidget

Comment: I think this is an overly complex solution as you can circumvent the issue by disabling the webview, calling reload() or setHtml() then re-enabling it in three lines of code! I would not have realised this without this answer though.

Comment: I like the typo (i think?) in your answer "For Qt 5.8 and ne**v**er" haha because it could be interpreted as a "don't do this" ^^

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem in my app in PyQt5. What I managed to do is to disable the whole widget like this (in Python):

```
view = PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
view.setEnabled(False)
```

This resulted in view being operational with mouse (it accepts mouse clicks and things can be changed on web page) but i won't take focus from different widget.

I would definitely call it a bug instead of feature in QtWebEngineWidgets.

Comment: +1 for the answer. In the beginning I also was thinking about such a solution, but because it disables keyboard input to the QWebEngineView, I had thought of how to circumvent this shortcoming. I posted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the others who provided answers for this. After encountering this bug I was somewhat stumped, but after learning of the way setEnabled(false) affects the focus stealing from the other answers I discovered that simply disabling the webview, setting the html or reloading it, then re-enabling it circumvents the issue (at least in Qt 5.7):

I.E.

```
myWebView->setEnabled( false );
myWebView->setHtml( html );
myWebView->setEnabled( true );
```

or

```
myWebView->setEnabled( false );
myWebView->reload();
myWebView->setEnabled( true );
```

This allows you to fix the problem without needing to subclass anything as one of the other answers suggests.